# Electromagnetic Brake Control Circuit

Tags: motor, inductor, zener, short-circuit, coil

I am troubleshooting a servo motor that is running while the brake is on when it shouldn't be. I have traced the control circuit for the brake as far back as made sense to. The brake is on a Panasonic motor and should be just an inductor - when 24V is applied the brake turns off, so it is used on a Z-axis to have a brake in case of power failure so a robot arm doesn't fall.

[![

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYtdeW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

][1]][1]

When I test the voltage on the connector that goes to the brake it has 24V until I connect the brake, then it shows 0V. I know that at constant current an inductor won't have a voltage drop across it but I thought that was only for ideal inductors - mine has ~90ohms resistance. The brake also doesn't actuate from the control circuit but if I hook up a 24VDC power supply to it it works to turn the brake off.

I am wondering what could be causing this and if it is something in the circuit controlling the brake. The brake is controlled by a PhotoMOS, http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/316/semi_eng_gu1a_aqv21_s-850760-932955.pdf

I've attached a drawing of the schematic and a simulation circuit just for testing (the sim circuit doesn't have the same components as the original) - and the simulation worked as expected, giving voltage across the inductor when the opto was conducting but none when it wasn't.

I would appreciate any help or advice[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the circuit you have shown. The brake will draw 267mA at 24 V, which is well in the capability of the optoMos (800mA DC continous, 60 V for each of the two FETs) to switch. The problem is most likely at the input side of the opto. You should try to rule out the rest of the circuit by supplying 5 mA at the input of the opto (e.g. with a 3 V button cell in series with a ~330 ohm resistor): if the brake deactivates you know that the control side is at fault. Also check the 24 V supply voltage.

Comment: looks like a blown chip

Comment: I tested the brake on an external power supply and it pulled ~260mA as expected. Also pulled the input pins up off the circuit board and supplied our own input and used the external power supply for the 24V - everything worked fine.
So as you suggested we are now checking the input to the opto and also the 24V supply it will actually be using on the robot arm (by applying it directly to the brake instead of through the opto circuit - don't worry I am going to put a flyback diode across it)